# Qt on Mac 11 Big Sur beta 5

Tags: qt, qml, macos-big-sur

I am using Qt QML C++ for developing desktop applications on Mac and Windows.
My all QML C++ applications hang on app startup on Mac 11 Big Sur. Whereas normal Qt Widget (non-QML) applications work fine.
Even Qt sample QML applications hang on startup.
Any pointer to resolve this issue is highly appreciated.

**Qt version: qt 5.12**

**Big Sur beta 5**

**Update**

Qt 5.15 works as expected.

Comment: Which Qt version is that?

Comment: qt 5.12, updated the question

Comment: well, maybe Qt is not checked with the beta version of Mac. Did you try updating to Qt5.15, if that doesn't impact your project?

Comment: @Chilarai it must be version check issue but how Qt5.15 can work. Is it released after Big Sur beta release?

Comment: True @Anil8753, it came before BigSur. But who knows what works and what not on the beta version as it is not properly tested. That's why I suggested

Comment: I tried building with Qt5.15, and it is working. Not sure what is the issue with Qt5.12 but Qt5.15 is working as expected.